# Use wildcards to recode field values in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

Hello I need to recode field values when a query is executed using MySQL, this is my scenario:

```
SELECT storename, sales FROM stores WHERE year = '2016' group by storename
```

This is the result:

```html
<HTML>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>StoreName</td><td>Sales</td></tr>
<tr><td>La quinta estacion y boulevard ok</td><td>1000</td></tr>
<tr><td>Centro Comercial Feria de Verano y otros</td><td>1000</td></tr>
<tr><td>Centro Comercial Metrogangas</td><td>2000</td></tr>
<tr><td>Centro Comercial Central</td><td>4000</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</HTML>
```

What I need to do is to recode the storename values to another ones, like zones, for example 'Centro Comercial Central' will be '**Zone 5**', 'Centro Comercial Metrogangas' will be '**Zone 4**' and so on; to accomplish this I am using this sentence:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN storename = 'Centro Comercial Metrogangas' THEN 'Zone 4' ELSE NULL END,
```

And it works but I would to ask you: Is it possible to use Wild Cards instead the entire storename? I am looking for a way to do this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN storename ='%Metro%' THEN 'Zone 4'
```

in fact I've already tried this way but it doesn't work, so any other suggestion will be welcome.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: You should use "LIKE" instead of "=" in the CASE statement.  But why don't you save the zones in the store table?

Comment: Why not add a lookup table for `Zones`? Then you wouldn't need several `Case` statements.

Comment: The only issue with doing the  LIKE way would be if you added another storename that matches the LIKE but is in a different zone. I think another lookup table would be the most efficient way to get what you're after.

Comment: Thanks everyone, It works with LIKE, it solves the problem, thank you